# I am creating Django web application for additional payments like Shift allowance on call etc, I am getting HttpResponse error

Tags: django

I am creating Django web application for additional payments like Shift allowance on call etc, I have created several apps under same, shift if one of the among applications, In this app, user will submit shift details and manager will approve it, here I am getting error when manager try to approve users shift details

ValueError at /shift/6/
The view shift.views.update_status didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/shift/6/
Django Version: 3.2.5
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:
The view shift.views.update_status didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Exception Location: C:\Users\vikasdange\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 309, in check_response
Python Executable:  C:\Users\vikasdange\Anaconda3\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.7
Python Path:
['C:\Users\vikasdange\django\additional_payments',
'C:\Users\vikasdange\Anaconda3\python39.zip',
'C:\Users\vikasdange\Anaconda3\DLLs',
'C:\Users\vikasdange\Anaconda3\lib',
'C:\Users\vikasdange\Anaconda3',
'C:\Users\vikasdange\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages',
'C:\Users\vikasdange\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\locket-0.2.1-py3.9.egg',
'C:\Users\vikasdange\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32',
'C:\Users\vikasdange\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\lib',
'C:\Users\vikasdange\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin']
Server time:    Sat, 23 Jul 2022 12:38:22 +0000
project name additional_payments

Project additional_payments urls.py file

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', include('login.urls')),
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('ot/', include('ot.urls')),
path('oncall/', include('oncall.urls')),
path('shift/', include('shift.urls')),
path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),     
]
```

app shift urls.py file

```
urlpatterns = [


path("shift", views.shift,name="shift"),
path("<int:id>/", views.update_status,name="update_status"),
path("shift_details/", views.shift_details,name="shift_details"),

]
```

app shift views.py file

```
def shift_details(request):
sdetails = Shift.objects.all()  
return render(request, 'shift_details.html', {'details':sdetails})
```

def update_status(request, id):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    ar_status = Shift.objects.get(pk=id)
    fm = shiftforms(request.POST,ar_status)
    if fm.is_valid():
        fm.save()
        return redirect('/')

else:
    ar_status=Shift.objects.get(id=id)
    fm = shiftforms(instance=ar_status)
    return render(request, "update.html", {"Shift":ar_status})
```

update.html file

```
  {% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h4>Approve Reject Request</h4>
<form action="" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{form.as_p}}

<table border="1">

    <tr>
        <td>Employee ID</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="id" value="{{Shift.id}}" readonly></td>
        
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Approval Status</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="status" value="{{Shift.status}}" ></td>
        
    </tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="Update">

<a href="{% url 'shift_details' %}">Back To Home</a>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no else if form is not valid. If form is not valid it should render the template with form errors like (and check if ar_status object exists) :

```
def update_status(request, id):
    try:
         ar_status = Shift.objects.get(pk=id)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
         print('There is no shift object with this id')
         return redirect('/')
    if request.method == 'POST':
       
        fm = shiftforms(request.POST, instance=ar_status)
        if fm.is_valid():
            fm.save()
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            print(fm.errors)
    else:
        ar_status=Shift.objects.get(id=id)
        fm = shiftforms(instance=ar_status)
    return render(request, "update.html", {"Shift":ar_status, "form": fm})
```

notice that the retun with render is no longer part of else statment.

Comment: Hey, Thanks lot for your response, it worked but, once I update status, it duplicates entry, Instead it should only update same entry 

Rohit Mali GTS 1234 sy@ts.com July 18, 2022 9 a.m. July 22, 2022 5 a.m. 5 1 Edit
Rohit Mali GTS 1234 sy@ts.com July 18, 2022 9 a.m. July 22, 2022 5 a.m. 5 2 Edit
Rohit Mali GTS 1234 sy@ts.com July 18, 2022 9 a.m. July 22, 2022 5 a.m. 5 4 Edit

Comment: maybe it should be: fm = shiftforms(request.POST, instance=ar_status) forget about 'instance' in POST if.